# Degrees of freedom and covariances

Tags: stata, degrees-of-freedom

I'm performing an estimation using Stata's `xtpcse` command, that's a Prais-Winsten regression, heteroskedastic panels corrected standard errors.

My sample has 589 observations, and in the results is noted:

```
Estimated covariances      = 101
Estimated autocorrelations = 1
Estimated coefficients     = 7
```

Does this mean that I have 480 degrees of freedom?

My doubt originates in the output of the `ereturn list` command, that states:

```
e(df_m) =  6
e(df)   =  5
```

In other words, the question is whether or not the covariances calculation diminish the Degrees of Freedom

Comment: Apparently the remaining degrees of freedom are in fact 480 (see [this](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/unstructured-covariance-matrix-when-it-does-and-doesn%E2%80%99t-work/)). Still don't know why Stata's `ereturn list` gives those results...